# Are there any way to send topic message to one device?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

As documentation says, I can send message with topic as

```
{
    "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
    "data": {
      "message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!",
    }
}
```

But to send message to specified device, i need to set `to` as device's push token as `"to":"cvE0coiuUEg:APA91..."`. But in this case, how should I set topic?

Comment: You should not set the topic if you are sending to a single device. Use a topic when you want to send to all subscribers to that topic, use InstanceID token when you want to send to a particular device. Not both together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are different types of messaging. You want to use Device Group Messaging. In that case, you do not need to set a topic.